# Synchronizing threads with conditional variables in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a C application, part of which does some threaded stuff, which I'm having some difficulty to implement. I'm using pthread.h ([POSIX thread programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)) as a guideline.

I need to synchronize two threads that repeat a certain task a predefined number of times, and with each repetition the two tasks need to start at the same time. My idea is to let each thread initialize and do their work before the sync'd task begins, and when this happens thread one (let's call this thread TX) will signal thread 2 (RX) that it can begin doing the task.

Here's an example:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t tx_condvar = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static bool tx_ready = false;
```

These are declared in a header file. The TX thread is shown below:

```
while (reps > 0 && !task->quit) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    tx_ready = true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&tx_condvar);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


    status = do_stuff();
    if (status != 0) {
        print_error();
        goto tx_task_out;
    }
    reps--;

    // one task done, wait till it's time to do the next
    usleep(delay_value_us);
    tx_ready = false;
}
```

And then the RX

```
while (!done && !task->quit) {
    // wait for the tx_ready signal before carrying on
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (!tx_ready){
        pthread_cond_wait(&tx_condvar, &mutex);
    }        
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    status = do stuff();

    if (status != 0) {
        print_error();
        goto rx_task_out;
    } 

    n = fwrite(samples, 2 * sizeof(samples[0]), to_rx, p->out_file);
    num_rx += to_rx;
    if (num_rx == s->rx_length){
        done = true; 
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this, and am I even doing it correctly? It's incredibly important that the two tasks within the tx/rx threads start at the same time for each repetition.

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: I'm not really an expert in this topic, but I think that semaphores could be useful here.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you mean “condition variable”, the synchronisation primitive used to avoid inefficient polling in concurrent programs (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-cv.pdf )

Comment: Is there a tolerance, say in uS, or pS that is an acceptable lapse between the actual starting of the two tasks?  i.e. what precision is required for _same time_ in your application?  Are you running a multi-core uP?

Comment: @ ryyker The application is running on my PC, which does have a multi core CPU, yes. There isn't a strictly defined tolerance, but off the top of my head I'd say anything more than 5-10 us would throw off my accuracy by a substantial margin.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29).  Basically it blocks threads entering the barrier until a certain number of threads have entered and then it releases them all.

I believe pthreads have a barrier, although it might be a extension.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_barrier_wait.txt

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of barriers. There's a nice example here http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.sys_arch%2Ftopic%2Fkernel_Barriers.html which I'm working through at the moment, will report findings in a while (hopefully)!

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are not using a multi-core processor, you cannot run two tasks at precisely the same time.

Starting two tasks at precisely the same time requires a multi-core system.  (SMP architecture where multiple cores with shared memory are under a single OS).  There are extensions available on several dev environments specifically for taking advantage of features such as ***[processor affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)***, where you can dedicate a particular thread to run only on a specific core, or set up processors to be dedicated to running specific threads, and when to run them.

I use LabWindows/CVI (ANSI C with extensions for instrumentation).  ***[HERE](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6728/en/)*** is a small white paper on capabilities using multi-core.  ***[Here is another](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6724/en/)*** that is mostly NI specific, but also includes some generic techniques applicable using any ANSI C compiler (toward bottom) dealing with time critical loops.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like exactly the tool I need to test execution times and establish some sort of baseline in terms of timing offset.